# The two kinds of a Cartesian product and how to specify which is used?

Tags: notation

I have already asked [a similar question](https://I%20have%20already%20asked%20this%20similar%20question,%20but%20it%20appears%20I%20must%20ask%20a%20more%20fundamental%20question%20about%20Cartesian%20products.%20%20%20In%20my%20experience,%20we%20normally%20notate%20in%20accordance%20with%20this%20expression:%20%20%20%7B1b2fce59-a1af-4652-9a93-3e3b37896ba8%7D), but it appears I must ask a more fundamental question about Cartesian products.

In my experience, we normally notate in accordance with this expression:

$$(s_1,s_2,\ \dots , s_n) \in S^n \tag1$$

However, some mathematicians mean something else by the Cartesian product:

$$((s_1,s_2),s_3) \in S^3$$

Or more generally (and less aesthetically pleasing):

$$((\cdots(s_1,s_2),s_3),s_4),\ \dots \ ), s_n) \in S^n \tag2$$

Now, perhaps everyone means this by a Cartesian product, but typically, context requires (and clearly implies) the use of $(1)$. Given the existence of a bijection between them, using $(1)$ in practice despite defining Cartesian products as $(2)$ is fine.

However, this raises problems. Firstly, how does one clearly specify which one is using? There are probably multiple ways and I am not asking for your opinions on which is best; simply, I want to know what options I have. In many cases, it might not be practically needed, but in some cases, it is. Especially when the use of $(1)$ and $(2)$ co-occur, as in the case that motivated my linked-to question. A set with elements that are tuples of tuples (of tuples, etc.) means that you want some elements to co-exist in the same, immediate tuple, and some to not; thus using both $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously.

How could one go about unambiguously notating such a thing? Or more generally, how does one specify exactly how one is using the Cartesian product?

Comment: If you define $X^n$ as $n$-tuples then $X^2\times X$ and $X^3$ and $X\times X^2$ are different objects you can distinguish. It's just that in most cases in practice we use them interchangeably through the obvious isomorphism, which is used implicitly and not mentioned.

Comment: Your question is really about specifying tuples.

Comment: I'm not aware of a good notation, however, I think of $A^B$ as the maps from $B$ to $A$ so $S^n$ would signal to me maps from $n$ (which in set theory equals $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$) to $S$ hence tuples of the form $(s_1,\dots,s_n)$.  The other thing I'd probably notate like $(S\times S)\times S$.